# Isn't the python code below, properly indented?

Tags: python, indentation

This is a small game I made. Simple rules, the player must determine the number in my mind. I will later import random module though.

```
print('Hello!, What is your name?')
userName = input()
print(myName + 'Welcome to Guess it! Ralph')
print('You must guess the number that I have in my mind(from 1 to 10) within 5 chances')
myNumber = 3

print('Give your prediction')

for no_of_chances in range(5, 0, -1):
    usersPrediction = input()
```

I get this error when I run in pycharm:
    if usersPrediction < myNumber:
    ^
    IndentationError: unexpected indent

```
    if usersPrediction < myNumber:
        print('It is lower than required,try a higher value')
    elif usersPrediction > myNumber:
        print('It is higher than required,try a lower value')
    elif usersPrediction == myNumber:
    print('yahoo!, you did it')

print('You always have a next chance, try it again')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent `print('yahoo!, you did it')`